# Calculus Made Easy Chapter 5, example 4 p. (30)

Tags: calculus

[First question] 
In ***Chapter 5, example 4*** of the ***Calculus Made Easy*** book I was having trouble understanding why the radius plugged in the formula is r=5.5 (as is correctly stated in the problem) yet when trying to check if the rate of variation is correct, the radius used is r(sub1)= 5 (and r(sub2)=6 but it is understandable since the problem aimed to find the rate of variation when r increases by 1 inch). When I attempted to manually verify the answer, it was correct. I want to understand why in checking, r(sub1) is always the r (used in the formula prior) minus 0.5.

[image: the problem]

Comment: Note the MSE question [For which value of $x$ is the average rate of change equal to the instantaneous rate of change?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155989/for-which-value-of-x-is-the-average-rate-of-change-equal-to-the-instantaneous) deals with a related issue to what you're asking, with this being that the average rate of change of a quadratic equation over a given range occurs at the center of the range. This is basically the first point of my answer, and I show it explicitly in the second part.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest, but not necessarily easiest, way to see the reason for using $r - 0.5$ for the lower value is to note that the derivative is a linear function of $r$. As such, the change in volume, given by the integral wrt $r$, over any distance, such as $1$ inch, would be the same as this distance times the rate of change at the middle of the range. This results in using the difference in volumes between $0.5$ in. more and $0.5$ in. less radius.

Another way to see is this is that it's due to the volume having a factor of the radius squared. Consider that, to check how the volume changes over a period of $1$ in. at $r_0 = 5.5$ we have

$$r_1 = r_0 - a, \text{ with } a \gt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$r_2 = r_0 + b, \text{ with } b \gt 0  \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$a + b = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

In other words, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are $2$ radii which are $1$ inch apart on either side of $r_0$. Next, note that

$$V_1 = \pi\left(r_0 - a\right)^2 h = \pi\left(r_0^2 - 2ar_0 + a^2\right) h \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
$$V_2 = \pi\left(r_1 + b\right)^2 h = \pi\left(r_0^2 + 2br_0 + b^2\right) h \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq5} - \eqref{eq4}, and using \eqref{eq3}, gives

$$V_2 - V_1 = \pi\left(2\left(a + b\right)r_0 + b^2 - a^2\right)h = \pi\left(2r_0 + b^2 - a^2\right)h \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

Note this is equal to

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 2\pi rh \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

at $r = r_0$ only if $b^2 - a^2 = 0$. Thus, this requires that $a = b = \frac{1}{2}$.

Overall, this shows you can use $0.5$ at any value of $r_0$. However, **note** this only works due to having terms using just $r^2$, $r$ and/or a constant in the original function, so the derivative is a linear function of the radius $r$. If any different power of $r$ was involved, such as $3$ for the volume of a sphere, then usually the difference in volumes at $0.5$ offsets would not be equal to the rate of change in volume at $r_0$.

Comment: I especially like the last paragraph here. The book is exploiting a special property of the particular function in the example without (in my opinion) properly acknowledging this. If someone were to naively apply the same logic elsewhere they could get wrong results. It seems to me a better title for the book would have been _Calculus Made Deceptively Easy._